# SQL - Sum two columns group by ID

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to sum two columns "Immo"+"Conso"  group by "ID" in order to create a new variable "Mixte". My new variable "Mixte" is as follow:

- if one ID has (at least) 1 in "Immo" AND 1 in "Conso" then "Mixte" is yes, otherwise "Mixte" is no.

For exemple:

```
Ident   | Immo  | Conso | Mixte
---------------------------------
1       | 0     | 1     | yes
1       | 1     | 0     | yes
2       | 1     | 0     | no
3       | 0     | 1     | no
3       | 0     | 1     | no
3       | 0     | 1     | no
4       | 0     | 1     | yes
4       | 0     | 1     | yes
4       | 1     | 0     | yes
```

Thank you for helping me. Do not hesitate to ask me questions if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Must your result show all records or would it suffice to show one row per Ident (and Immoand Conso are not shown in the results, only Ident and Mixte)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ident,result=(case when sum(Immo)>0 and sum(Conso)>0 then 'yes' 
               else 'no' end)
from tabname (NOLOCK)
group by id
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a correlated sub-select:

```
select t1.Ident, t1.Immo, t1.Conso,
       case when (select max(Immo) + max(Conso) from tablename t2
                  where t2.Ident = t1.Ident) = 2 then 'yes'
            else 'no'
       end as Mixte
from tablename t1
```

`Ident` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit it as `"Ident"`.

Comment: Dos it work in sas? When I am doing my proc sql, it gives me an error... The case content looks not ok for sas.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the smoothiest way but I'll do this as:

```
    WITH X AS 
    (
    SELECT T.Ident, MAX(T.Immo) Immo, MAX(T.Conso) Conso FROM Table AS T
    GROUP BY T.Ident
    )

    SELECT X.*
    ,CASE WHEN X.Immo > 0 AND X.Conso > 0 THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO' 
    END Mixte
    FROM X
```

Comment: This looks completely wrong. To start with, the cte gives you one record with two columns, both equal 1. And there is no Ident column in your cte. So you cannot read from the cte and group by Ident. And a result showing a mere list of yesses and nos is certainly also not desired.

Comment: You are right about the 2nd part, but I can't agree with the first one. CTE should give two column, both equal to at least 1, if the parameters have their value equal to at least 1.

Comment: I was referring to the sample that contain both records with immo=1 and with conso=1, so the query's result would have been (1,1). Now you have changed your query and fixed that. The query looks a bit more complicated than need be, but works okay - provided the OP is fine with only one result row per Ident. (My question concerning that has not yet been answered by the OP).

Comment: Oh, right. My result is quite different than OP's example. He needs to decide what he is fine with.

And yea, I know my answer is not as simple as it should be, but hey... I am here to learn also :) thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you could try to use `window functions`, something like:

```
select Ident, Immo, Conso, 
       case when rn1 > 0 and rn2 > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Mixte
from (
    select
           max(Immo) over (partition by Ident) rn1,
           max(Conso) over (partition by Ident) rn2,
           *
    from table_name
)x
```